# Why is my log showing a partial rendered twice Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to show an easier example of the same thing:

```
Started GET "/greetings/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-09-29 15:30:46 +0700
  Processing by GreetingsController#new as JS
  Board Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "boards".* FROM "boards" WHERE "boards"."id" = 12 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Upload Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "uploads".* FROM "uploads" WHERE ("uploads".uploadable_id = 1 AND "uploads".uploadable_type = 'User') LIMIT 1
Rendered greetings/_greeting_form.html.erb (108.9ms)
Rendered greetings/_greeting_form.html.erb (4.1ms)
Rendered greetings/new.js.erb (116.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 302ms (Views: 126.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
```

The log shows that the _greeting_form.html.erb is being rendered twice. The partial is rendered with an Ajax call to the controller.

Controller:

```
 def new
    @greeting = Greeting.new
    @user = current_user || User.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render :action => 'new'}
    end
  end
```

new.js.erb

```
    if($('#boxGreeting').length == 0){
$('#buttons').after($(" <%=escape_javascript(render 'greeting_form', :user => @user, :greeting => @greeting) %>").fadeIn('fast'));      

            }
            else
            {
            $('#boxGreeting').replaceWith("<%=escape_javascript(render 'greeting_form', :user =>@user, :greeting => @greeting)%>");
            }
```

Comment: You should attach new template and the partial to your question, so we can see what's going on, if it's in the log it is rendered, I would then put a debugger at the very beginning of the partial and count how many times it gets triggered (you can do it with a log line as well)

Comment: It's possible you've got the statement rendering `invite_form` in a loop - check to make sure your partials are only rendered once if that's your intention.

Comment: How can I add a debugger to count how many times a page gets rendered?

Comment: I have placed a counter in the partial _greeting_form.html.erb and it is being rendered twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `render 'greeting_form'` twice in your `new.js.erb`. If you look into the output .js file in your browser you will see that the partial appears twice.

The browser will later evaluate your javascript if-clause and use either the first or the second of the pre-rendered "greeting_form" partials.

You can avoid parsing it twice by assigning the render result to a variable and then use this variable within the if or else part:

```
var greeting_form = " <%=escape_javascript(render 'greeting_form', :user => @user, :greeting => @greeting) %>";
if($('#boxGreeting').length == 0) {
    $('#buttons').after($(greeting_form).fadeIn('fast'));      
}
else {
    $('#boxGreeting').replaceWith(greeting_form);
}
```

Comment: You are a rock star. Thanks for clearing that up it works perfectly.